# Optimising Inventory

Tags: optimization, operations-research

I have x number of items to sell. Each item must be sold as part of a bundle and **must not** be sold alone. Each bundle contains three items which must be different from each other. Therefore if I had four items (listed as: A, B, C and D) to sell (x = 4) I would have four different bundles (A,B,C; A,B,D; A,C,D and B,C,D) that I could potentially sell. It is important to me that all of my stock sells out and I am not left with any surplus. Each item will have its own level of inventory (say in this example: A = 100, B = 120, C = 85 and B =92).

So I would like to construct an optimisation problem whereby I can model exactly how many of each specific bundle I should sell in order to sell all of my stock. I am seeking a general model and approach as an answer but am unsure whether this can realistically be obtained.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to minimize or maximize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the specific bundles be $x_1 (ABC), x_2(ABD), x_3(ACD),x_4(BCD)$ respectively.

Then the optimization problem is

Max $x_1+ x_2+ x_3+x_4$

s.t

$x_1+ x_2+ x_3=100$

$x_1+ x_2+ x_4=120$

$x_1+ x_3+x_4 = 85$

$x_2+ x_3+x_4 = 92$

$x_i$ is integer

$x_i\ge 0$

I ran it in EXCEL, you don't have a feasible solution for you not to have any surplus.  But if you changed the A to be $=99$, then the optimal solution is

$x_1=40, x_2=47, x_3=12,x_4=33$

Max bundles $= 132$

Comment: Hi Satish, thanks for your reply! My EXCEL skills are a little bit out of date and I was just wondering how you managed to use the software to solve this problem?

Comment: Go ahead!! Shoot it

Comment: You may have to add the Add-in called "Solver" in EXCEL, Please google and find out how you can add the Add in.  Once you have added that shoot me an email and I will walk you through.

Comment: Ok I've added Solver so fire away!

Comment: Actually I've managed to trial and error my way to making it work. Thanks very much for all your help, really appreciate it Satish!

Comment: You are welcome and I am sorry, it was night when you had posted your comment. It is good that you figured it out on your own.  I am happy for you!!